# Why are the falling buildings still there?

Tags: patema-inverted

The movie [*Patema Inverted*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patema_Inverted) (2013) is wonderfully complex.  If you haven't seen the movie, you should go watch it first.  Seriously.  This is why pretty much everything needs to be in spoiler tags.

In the movie, it is revealed that:

> The citizens of Aiga are the actual antigravity survivors. They live in an underground constructed world that machines make to look real.  The "inverts" are actually the ones with ordinary gravity.
> At the end of the movie, we see Patema in the real world, along with some characters from Aiga, looking out at the ruined buildings.

However:

> Why are the ruined buildings still there at all?  After the gravity accident, then all those buildings would have drifted off into space, right?  Aiga would have then been built underground for everyone who survived.
> But... the buildings are still there!  In normal gravity!  For that matter, why do the "invert"s live underground in the first place, instead of on the surface?  And where is everybody else on the planet for that matter?

But seriously--about those buildings--what gives?

Comment: This feels like a real-world-science kind of question